# How to create fixed count for every row with % ratio ignoring filters

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I'm working on a problem which I try to illustrate on below example.

[image]

1 is my table. As you can see, I have some people with their attributes and with business units their belong to (main BU and Sub-BU). What I have now in Power BI is the 2 view. That was quite easy to do.

But right now, I need implement view 3 and create new column that shows percentage ratio. I need to calculate number of names in BUs and Sub-BUs that will not change regardless of chosen attribute. I've tried different measures but cannot get the right values.

This is just an example model. The one I'm working on has many tables and relations. Names are in one, Attributes in another and BUs and Sub-BUs in another one.

I will appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REMOVEFILTER function to remove filter context for the Count of Names.
Something like this:

Count Names Ignoring Attribute Selection =
CALCULATE (
[Count of Names],
REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table 1'[Attributes] )
)

Comment: Hi @Syed Rehan Ali. Thanks for this. And yes, partially it resolve my issue but unfortunately, when I filter by attributes I still get list with all names - not only of these people that have that particular attribute. But I'm not quite sure if what I want can be accomplished on one graph. On one side I want to remove filters like you advised but on the other hand I need to filter the list by the same field. I will work this out. Your answer was helpful thought and it led me to the right conclusions. So thanks :)